# Relaxed approach in/at/towards solving

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What is the difference between the following and are they correct?

1. He took a relaxed approach in solving the problem.
2. He took a relaxed approach at solving the problem.
3. He took a relaxed approach towards solving the problem.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: I think they're all valid sentences.

Comment: Normally, "towards" or "to" would be preferred.  "At" is probably least idiomatic.  "In" has a *slightly* different implication from "towards/to", but the difference is hard to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 1  is valid but uncommon, and 2 would not normally be used in British English. Number 3 is perfectly fine but wouldn't be commonly used. The most commonly-used formation would be:

> He took a relaxed approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I think the lack of response thus far suggests there is no clear answer. English is funny: It has evolved. Changes can be made without altering meaning. Sometimes a change can be understood, but it would be obvious you were non-native. However, your example is not like that. I would use "towards" because I think it flows better, but none of the three prepositions you chose would be inappropriate.